# Product page doesn't show right set up

Tags: magento-1.9

I am rebuilding our webstore at the moment, and we are using a new theme that is installed over our old one. At the moment I am facing the following problem:

When i go to the product page, the layout how it should be is way different than what the installed demo looks like:
[image: how it should be]

Now our one looks like the following:

[image: How it looks]

[image: How it looks 2]

What is going wrong where? Did i do something wrong in the xml files? I have set up the right one but i think its making a mistake somewhere.

you can find the site here: tfgs.hypernode.io

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if:

1. You have incorrectly configured your xml layout file, as compare products block is using your left column as oppose to the right as you intend.
2. Check your template files/css for any conflicts in regards to other positioning elements.

Comment: 1. I did not touch my xml files. If i set it to the right column version then it doesn't work either. 2. How can i find a conflict in CSS files? It loads the css of the theme i select right?